# python filter csv row

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Ive a csv file .  Im trying to check each row by 2 variables.

```
 csv:
 1,2
 1,3
 2,3
 3,2
 8,5
```

**script:**

```
 import csv
 a= 2
 b= 3

 with open('ondo.csv','r') as rows1:
 for row in rows1: 
         if (str(a) and str(b)) in row:
            print ('oops')
         else:
            print (row)
```

Produces

```
1,2

oops
oops
oops
8,5
```

2 and 3 are supposed to be found in 2 rows only . Whats the right way to filter and what causes the newline in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[ NB: I'm assuming that `for row in rows1:` should be indented another level ]]

The problem is that `(str(a) and str(b))` evaluates to `'3'`, so `if (str(a) and str(b)) in row:` is the same as `if '3' in row:`.
The first row (`1, 2`) doesn't contain `'3'`, so it is printed (including it's attached newline and one from print for free).  The last line (`8, 5`) also does not contain `'3'`, so it is printed.  Either the file does not end in a newline, or you didn't notice the blank line at the end of the output.

The condition you want is:

```
if str(a) in row and str(b) in row:
```

but that's really not the best way to do this, since it would be `True` for a line that has `23` in it (the CSV module is your friend here).  There is also no reason not to define `a` and `b` as `'2'` and `'3'`, since you only use them as strings.